# How do I set vertical text to be left-to-right in Microsoft Word for Mongolian?

Tags: language, text-formatting, microsoft-word-365

In Microsoft Word, is it possible to write text vertically, in columns from left to right? This is the writing order of the traditional Mongolian script. None of the options in the Text Direction dialog here would do that. Currently, the text is in vertical columns from right to left, which is correct for traditional Chinese, Japanese, and Korean, but not Mongolian. Pressing the button to make the text Left to Right doesn't do anything.

[image: Mongolian text in Microsoft word, vertical in columns from left to right.]

Here is what it should look like (from https://r12a.github.io/scripts/mongolian/):

[image: Mongolian text in columns from left to right]

The text is: ᠬᠦᠮᠦᠨ ᠪᠦᠷ ᠲᠥᠷᠥᠵᠦ ᠮᠡᠨᠳᠡᠯᠡᠬᠦ ᠡᠷᠬᠡ ᠴᠢᠯᠥᠭᠡ ᠲᠡᠢ᠂ ᠠᠳᠠᠯᠢᠬᠠᠨ ᠨᠡᠷ᠎ᠡ ᠲᠥᠷᠥ ᠲᠡᠢ᠂ ᠢᠵᠢᠯ ᠡᠷᠬᠡ ᠲᠡᠢ ᠪᠠᠢᠠᠭ᠃ ᠣᠶᠤᠨ ᠤᠬᠠᠭᠠᠨ᠂ ᠨᠠᠨᠳᠢᠨ ᠴᠢᠨᠠᠷ ᠵᠠᠶᠠᠭᠠᠰᠠᠨ ᠬᠦᠮᠦᠨ ᠬᠡᠭᠴᠢ ᠥᠭᠡᠷ᠎ᠡ ᠬᠣᠭᠣᠷᠣᠨᠳᠣ᠎ᠨ ᠠᠬᠠᠨ ᠳᠡᠭᠦᠦ ᠢᠨ ᠦᠵᠢᠯ ᠰᠠᠨᠠᠭᠠ ᠥᠠᠷ ᠬᠠᠷᠢᠴᠠᠬᠥ ᠤᠴᠢᠷ ᠲᠠᠢ᠃

Comment: I guess Word doesn't support such features and you need to use a different type setting tool like TeX: [Manchu and Mongolian script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87259/79491)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install "Traditional Mongolian" first to your language setting. Then the text direction should have an option of "Vertical for Mongolian". I hope it helps.